# Under what circumstances is it possible that parent fields are not inherited?

Tags: php, inheritance

I've got a curious bug (bugging me) today. There are three inheritance levels involved:

**Grandpa**:

```
abstract class Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract implements ArrayAccess, 
                                                     IteratorAggregate
{
    protected $_data = array();

    /* snip */
}
```

**Mom**:

```
namespace Survey\Db\Table\Row;

class AbstractRow extends \Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract
{
    /* snip */
}
```

**Child**:

```
namespace Survey\Db\Table\Row;

class SurveyItem extends AbstractRow implements ISkippable
{
    /* snip */
}
```

**Exception**:

```
Type:     ErrorException  
Value:    Undefined property: Survey\Db\Table\Row\SurveyItem::$_data  
Location: [...]/Zend/Db/Table/Row/Abstract.php in handleError , line 177
```

Line 177 doesn't seem to be relevant, but I'm adding it just so you'd believe me ;)

```
if (!array_key_exists($columnName, $this->_data)) {
```

> PHP 5.4.11, problem did NOT exist with PHP 5.4.8

When I saw the [fix](https://github.com/smalyshev/php-src/commit/d1da4c6fe71d18966f07f48aaa62c7bc06c2babe) for [Bug #63462 Magic methods called twice for unset protected properties](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63462), I thought, that wold solve the problem, since this bug leads to exactly the weird unexpected outcome I was seeing.

But it turns out, the **problem still exists after updating to PHP 5.4.12**. The likelyhood that there is another similar bug in PHP seems quite high.

**Question:**

I get the info that a protected field defined in the Grandpa is undefined in the Child. What scenarios can lead to such an outcome?

Comment: Can you add a little more context to the reference of `$this->_data`. Include the class and method from which it's being referenced. The code, as you posted looks like child should have access to the member var, I'm wondering if you need to namespace AbstractRow when extending via SurveyItem.

Comment: I've tried this on 5.3.20, using empty classes (making the parent and child classes abstract so it compiles) and it's all fine. Try that on your current PHP version, to ensure that it isn't something in Zend (maybe some PHP magic) that is getting in the way? If it worked on an earlier version 5.4 however, and nothing else has changed, then it must be a PHP bug.

Comment: It could be some PHP 'magic'. I'm trying to improve the question to give you more context.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to understand it, thanks to the newsfeed on the chat. I think it's a bug in PHP, magic __set() and __get() are called twice under some circumstances. Line 177 actually happens in the context of magic methods.

Comment: Upgrading to 5.4.12 didn't solve the problem!

Comment: Hi @markus. I have the same problem (but not always): a property defined in the Parent is undefined in the Child, but i do not use magic methods.

I have seen it debugging with PHPStorm but not sure if it is related to PHP or xDebug  (which i have activated) or APC (it would not be the first time we have problems with op-cache).

Have you fix it? Any advices?

Comment: Hi @aanton, we never actually found out what exactly it was. We just upgraded our whole stack to using PHP 5.5 and the problem never came back. I think the PHP versions around 5.4.9 (+/- 3 versions) are exceptionally buggy resp. don't play well with opcache and other stuff. It's just not a stable place to be. 5.5 with integrated opcache is so much better in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

following snippet works flawlessly on PHP 5.4.9:

```
class A
{
    protected $foo = 'hello';
    public function bar()
    {
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}

class B extends A {}

class C extends B {}

$c = new C();
$c->bar();
```

Please minimise your code step by step to this to see if/when problem occurs (I wonder why you haven't done it already)

If you are sure this worked on PHP 5.4.8 and does not work on PHP 5.4.11 then you found a bug in PHP and should be reporting it on php.net

Answer may be different (maybe it simply got 'unset' along the way).
Minimise your code and you will know.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the parent field to inherit in the child class through object then declar the parent field as "static".